# Set display brightness to 0% after some time of inactivity. And back to original value after user input

Tags: android, brightness

I'm writing an app for Android (2.1+). And I need to solve problem with brightness of display. App will be running for longer time and if user is inactive (for example 30 seconds) it should set brightness to 0% and after touch on screen restore original value.

Now I'm using

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "DimScreen");
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
wl.release();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
wl.acquire();
}
```

But this won't set brightness to 0%. And battery drain is higher.
It is possible to set brightness to 0% (no turn off the display) and restore original value **just by touching** the screen ? And device should not lock itself while app is running.

Thanks in advance.
kamelot_sk

Comment: Might be that the screen does not support a '0%' brightness. Have you verified that you can dim the screen to a lower brightness than what you get using the program? (using the settings app or a third-party app)

Comment: thanks, I've tested it now, I can't get lower brightness even via manual setting. So my question is: It is possible to completly turn off display and wake it by touch? (no power/home button pressing)

Answer (score 0):

Only way to have app running while the screen is off is to use a partial wakelock, but this doesn't fit your requirement of turning on the screen again just by touching it and not having to press the power button.

Another way to do what you want is to use the method 'hardware.setScreenBacklight' inputting an integer value to dim the screen to as low as possible. Also using 'android:keepScreenOn="true"' within the XML view layout for your class to make sure the screen is always on while the app is open.

Comment: thanks, it's good idea, but it will dim screen at once. And I wanted to make dimming constatnt and fluent downto zero (or very close).